# React w/SignalR - TypeError: WebSocketClient() not a constructor

Tags: node.js, api, reactjs, websocket, signalr

new to React development.

I am building an API client for the BitTrex Exchange API, using their node.js wrapper: [node.bittrex.api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node.bittrex.api)

With the objective of simply testing the websocket subscription for orderbook updates within the ReactJS framework, here are the steps I have taken:

-Used create-react-app to create the app.
-used npm to install the node.bittrex.api
-added the bittrex client object to the top of the default App.js component and configured options with proper API keys
-added a button (with handler, binded to the button according to React docs) to the default App.js main component,
-inside the handler function, initiated the websocket subscription according to the example code in the node.bittrex.api docs.

The app comes up, but when I press the button, I get an error saying that TypeError Websocketclient() is not a constructor, in the line inside the SignalR.js that creates the websocket connection:

[image]

Now I suspect that there is just something specific with the React framework that is screwing this up. Can anyone please help me understand the intricacies? Thanks. Here is my App.js:

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

var bittrex = require('../node_modules/node.bittrex.api/node.bittrex.api.js');
bittrex.options({
      'apikey' : process.env.REACT_APP_BTREX_API_KEY,
      'apisecret' : process.env.REACT_APP_BTREX_SECRET_KEY, 
      'verbose' : true,
      'cleartext' : false, 
      'baseUrl' : 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1'
    });



class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    bittrex.websockets.subscribe(['BTC-ETH','BTC-ANS','BTC-GNT'], function(data) {
      if (data.M === 'updateExchangeState') {
        data.A.forEach(function(data_for) {
          console.log('Market Update for '+ data_for.MarketName, data_for);
        });
      }
    });


  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Start WS Sub</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Im going to restructure this to use React + Redux, with SignalR 'middleware' functions (instead of using the node.bittrex.api wrapper), a la this article: https://medium.com/@lucavgobbi/signalr-react-redux-5a100a226871

Comment: Any answer to this question?